# angular.js ng-repeat with arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a simple shopping cart app with angular.js, working quite well.

Customer adds product to the cart, obtaining an object like this (just pasting little) :

```
shoppingCart {
    cartName: "Store",
    items: Array[2]
        0: Object
        name: "product1"
        price: 3.5
        quantity: 1
        sku: "1906"

        1: Object
        name: "product2"
        price: 5
        quantity: 1
        sku: "1907"
        }
```

Now, people can make different orders, and they're receiving products at the bar before proceeding to checkout and pay).

I have a summary page with an ng-repeat directive to show all products (and + - buttons to make last correction). Once reviewed the cart, the customer click on a order-button.
After ordering, cutsomers can continue shopping and in the same summary page i would like to show, on top, all orders already fulfilled (without + - buttons as the products were already delivered).

i tried moving the content of the shoppingCart object inside another object, but i'm using array.push, and can't figure out how to ng-repeating with an array.

```
$scope.alreadyDeliveredProducts = {
    'itemsAlready' : []
    };

$scope.pushmyorders = function (){
    $scope.alreadyDeliveredProducts.itemsAlready.push($scope.cart.items);
    // and then clear Store
    }
```

now my alreadyDeliveredProducts is like this:

```
Object {
    itemsAlready: Array[2]
        0: Array[2] //contains all items of first order
        1: Array[3] //contains all items of second order
    }
```

should sound good but now i dont' know how to iterate on this collection.

tried something like this, and it's not correct, but i can0t do better, for now:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="ordereditem in alreadyDeliveredProducts.itemsAlready track by $index">
<p> {{ordereditem.name}} </p>
```

Sorry for this long question, but perhaps (sure) all my strategy to store data could be improved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here:`$scope.alreadyDeliveredProducts.itemsAlready.push($scope.cart.items);`
Try to change to this: `[].push.apply($scope.alreadyDeliveredProducts.itemsAlready, $scope.cart.items);`

Comment: worked like a charm! and.. reading again my question, i can't get a) why i wrote it so badly b) how could you, anyway, provide the solution.

Comment: btw, i'm reading for the first time about push and apply on MDN, and i still can't figure it very well :) thanks, anyway and i'm definitely "infatuated" with stackoverflow!!